# apt: Install all php packages whatsoever

Tags: shell-script, debian, apt, apache-httpd, php

I'm quite fed up with tracking packages of PHP extensions that are needed for some GUIs like PHPMyAdmin or some CMSs like Drupal.

For example, I once did:

```
apt upgrade php-{cli,curl,mbstring,mcrypt,gd}
```

but now `mcrypt` is deprecated.

Also, in Arch Linux, some php-extension packages are included OOB in the `php` package.

Is there an `apt` command to install all PHP packages whatsoever that I could run after `apt install lamp-server^` to save all this tracking?

Maybe `apt install php` is exactly what I need? <sub>Pilot6 thank you !</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt install` will match substring regexes if the package name is given with `.`, `?` or `*`, so

```
sudo apt install php.*
```

will install all packages with names containing `php`.

(This isn’t a good idea.)

Comment: This will install all versions of `php` as well from 1.x-7.x and all their remaining extensions, right? This could be 1 gb or more if so.

Comment: No, it can’t invent packages, so it won’t install PHP 1, 2 etc. In Debian 9 it will install PHP 7.0 and all available extensions (and debug packages if you have the debug repositories in your list of sources). You asked for a “command to install all PHP packages whatsoever”; this is such a command.

Answer (score 2):

```
 apt-get install `apt-cache search php- | grep ^php- | cut '-d ' -f1`
```

The result may not be pretty:  on my debian + deb-multimedia system this finds 408 packages.