# apt: What's the difference between "apt install php" and "apt install php-defaults"?

Tags: debian, php, defaults, stability

What's the difference between `apt install php` and `apt install php-defaults`?

In a first glimpse I would theorize that `php` should include everything default for a (latest) php program.

I ask this as a follow up to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503940/apt-install-latest-stable-php-and-all-its-extensions).

Comment: Note that the referenced Q&A nowhere says to run `apt install php-defaults`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that

```
apt install php-defaults
```

doesn’t work, because [`php-defaults`](https://packages.debian.org/source/php-defaults) is a source package, not a binary package.

A source package contains the source code and packaging descriptors used to build one or more binary packages. Source packages aren’t directly installable.